# How do I display the wordpress admin bar outside wordpress?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Is there a way I can display the wordpress admin bar outside of wordpress? (for example on an external html page or something)

Comment: By 'external page' do you mean 'external site'? The admin bar should display on all pages once logged in (dependent on your user role)

Comment: I mean a html page, on the same site, that's independent of wordpress (eg. not a wordpress post or page)

Comment: There's no point including the bar unless you know that someone is logged in (and who they are logged in as). Unless you parse PHP it's impossible to tell whether or not someone is logged in (unless you've got your server set to parse PHP on .html pages?).

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do, the html page will only be visible for logged in users, the reason why I'm using a separate html page and not one of wordpress' pages is because of php. Is this possible to do?

Comment: It's not really possible unless you set your server to parse PHP for pages with .html extensions, you could copy the HTML and add it in manually but you'd have to remove certain parts, e.g. the "Howdy username" part, it's impossible to tell who's logged in without running PHP in this case.

Comment: Php does work in my html pages, thats' the reason why I can't do this with a wordpress page, because php doesn't work on wordpress pages or posts

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I think it is not possible. That page is essentially treated as an external site, because it would be one level higher (at least) in your site folder.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to load the WordPress environment in that page and then load the [admin bar](http://codex.wordpress.org/Toolbar).

I think that it worth the try.

**Disclaimer:** I didn't tested by myself!

For instance, in your file do:

```
    /** Loads the WordPress Environment */
require(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../../../wp-load.php');

    // Some other code to check some various things.

    // Code to load the adminbar here.
    // Add Toolbar Menus
    function custom_toolbar() {
        global $wp_admin_bar;

    }

    // Hook into the 'wp_before_admin_bar_render' action
    add_action( 'wp_before_admin_bar_render', 'custom_toolbar', 999 );
```

See http://generatewp.com/toolbar/ for an easy to use toolbar code generator.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, got it to work by taking Sean Dunwoody's advice of copying and pasting the admin bar code onto my page. I then managed to load the user's name into the admin bar, and it looks identical to the one on the site. Thanks everyone for the help

Comment: Sometimes the simplest solution is the best! Congrats on getting it working :)